# Problems with correct keymap in rdesktop

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop

I am using rdesktop frequently to access my university PC from home via vpn.
rdesktop is running smooth and without a problem, only the keymap is always wrong. My language setup is en_US, but my locale is de_DE.UTF-8.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this question with the answer because I was searching the internet for quite some time and yet there is no good answer for this simple problem. When I did a standard `sudo apt-get install rdesktop` the program installed nicely and everything worked fine, except for one thing: no keymaps were installed. Normally rdesktop can use different keymaps by providing the option -k, e.g. `-k de` for german keyboard layout. Those keymaps have to be stored in the folder ~/.rdesktop/keymaps, which was empty in my case. By default rdesktop then falls back to en-us (see `man rdesktop`).
So the only thing that has to be done is to find the right keymaps file and store it there.

You can find the files here [packages.debian.org/en/sid/i386/rdesktop/download](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/i386/rdesktop/download)

Unpack and you find the keymaps under: rdesktop_1.8.3-1_i386/usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps

Copy and paste in the above mentioned folder solves the problem.

Comment: it seems the keymaps are in /usr/bin/desktop already, but creating ~/.rdekstop and moving them here worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it never is a good idea to copy out something that might get updated. If you use a shortcut on the desktop just add e.g. for a German keyboard: "-k /usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps/de". Or add a hardlink from "~/.rdesktop/keymaps/" to "/usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps/".

Now looking were my "@" and "µ" is. Looks like "Alt Gr" does not work yet.

Answer (score -2):

The answer from derwahre_tj is correct, but you do not need to download the package again.
The keymaps files will be installed to /usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps when the rdesktop package is installed on your system. Instead of downloading the files again, simply copy the files from the system dir.

First create the rdesktop keymaps dir in your home directory

```
mkdir -p ~/.rdesktop/keymaps
```

Next copy the files from your /usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps

```
cp /usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps/* ~/.rdesktop/keymaps/
```

Note that this will copy all the keymaps files, but you can instead simply copy the ones you need.